# Move finger across buttons in android apps

Tags: android, touch, touch-event, ontouchlistener

When the user touches the button sound shoud be played. There is a lot of buttons, and each has a different sound. When user move finger across all buttons, all sounds should be played. Something like piano app. How can I do it? I tried with ontouch lister but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Within your onTouch method, you should capture different events starting from user TouchDown followed by TouchMove and finally TouchUp. Look for all x,y co-ordinates whether in your button area, if so, play sound.

Make sure that the current button selection is different than the previous one otherwise, if your finger moves over same button, that'll trigger another event for same button and you'll here tons of sound while moving finger:

psudo code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(event.getAction())
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:     // stop here
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // start here
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   
            // See if new x y co-ordinates in your buttonRect area 
            // RectF [] buttonRect = new buttonRect[10] ;
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if( buttonRect[i].contains(event.getX(), event.getY()))
                {
                    // if it's a new button found than previously touch, play a sound

                    // store the button number that's been tapped by user

                }
            }


        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.